# which property should I choose to set "text" HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change text in P or other tag in HTML with Java Script

I tried to many different ways.
However, any of those didn't work well.

Console says.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

```
<script>
//1 document.getElementById("stackoverflow").textContent="newtext";
//2 document.getElementById("stackoverflow").value ="newtext";
//3 document.getElementById("stackoverflow").innerHTML ="newtext";

<script>
 <div class="row">
<p id="stackoverflow">I wanna change this text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p>` don't have a `.value` - so ... 1 down, 2 to go - if you want text, and NO html, use `.textContent` - if you want to include html, use `.innerHTML` - Amazing!!! what to use is in the name!!!!

Comment: `stack overflow` != `stackoverflow`

Comment: your id is "stackoverflow", but you are selecting on "stack overflow".

Comment: and `id = id="tsackoverflow"` may break the interwebs

Comment: Thank you guys. I modified "id" . but it still occurs error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes

1. move your script after element is loaded
2. remove id from markup
   below code works

```js
document.getElementById("stackoverflow").textContent="newtext";
```

```html
<p id="stackoverflow">I wanna change this text</p>
```

Comment: Thank you . I tried your code on my browser.however, the console says. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

Comment: try this: <body>
<p id="stackoverflow">I wanna change this text</p>
<script>

document.getElementById("stackoverflow").textContent="newtext";
//2 document.getElementById("stackoverflow").value ="newtext";
//3 document.getElementById("stackoverflow").innerHTML ="newtext";

</script>
</body>

Comment: you can access the element only after html tag is loaded.

Comment: I realised  scripts are loaded before html tags . I modified the order. then it went well.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your id there is no space in between.
id is **stackoverflow** and your giving document.getElementById("**stack overflow**")

Answer (score 0):

That is completly normal as long as you have two `id` attributes on the `p` tag only the first one will be consider.

```js
let p = document.getElementById("stackoverflow");
console.log(p);
```

```html
<p id id="stackoverflow">This is a sample paragraph</p>
```

But when you remove the first `id` it should work as expected

```js
let p = document.getElementById("stackoverflow")
console.log(p);
```

```html
<p id="stackoverflow">This is a sample paragraph</p>
```

```js
let p = document.querySelector("p");

console.log(p.id);
```

```html
<p id id="stackoverflow">This is a sample paragraph</p>
```

As you can see the `id`attribute is **empty**

Answer (score 0):

- Place always your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag
- Close properly the `</script>` tag

```html
<head>
  <!-- HEAD stuff goes here. link, meta, title etc -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <p id="stackoverflow">I wanna change this text</p>
  </div>


  <!--
    SCRIPTs go here before the closing </body>  
  -->
  <script>
    document.getElementById("stackoverflow").textContent="newtext";
  </script>
</body>
```

Additional read on [parser blocking versus asynchronous javascript](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript#parser_blocking_versus_asynchronous_javascript)

Comment: "in a non render-blocking manner." this is not true. Having a script at the end of the markup will still block the rendering just like if it were in the head. To not block the rendering fetching the script should take longer than needed to perform the first paint, and to help in this , the `async` attribute is the closest we have.

Comment: @Kaiido `async` is the closest we have for external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways , 
1 - if you are doing onload event , u can wrap this within your body tag and call your function 
2 - if its onlclick event , call this function onclick event
remove comment on button and onload = "ChangeEvent()"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
    function ChangeEvent() {
      document.getElementById("stackoverflow").textContent = "HI";
    }
    </script>
    
<body onload="ChangeEvent()">
    <p id="stackoverflow">Change</p>
    <!-- <button onclick="ChangeEvent()">Clicked</button> -->
</body>
</html>
```